# Webpack HMR does not work with `localhost`, only with `--host=[::1]`

Tags: javascript, windows, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

It all started when I tried to use the hot reload for `storybook`, which worked fine on my Macbook, but for whatever reason didn't work on my Windows machine.

I always got a request to `__webpack_hmr` which would be in the `pending`-state für about 10 seconds after which it got `cancelled` and then this cycle would start again.

Since I was running into the same problem with the very basic example from the [webpack-hot-middleware GitHub](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-middleware/tree/master/example) I could rule out `storybook`.

After a bit of playing around with the example I finally figured out that when using `--host=[::1]` to start the "server" the hot reload actually started to work. But no luck using anything else like `--host=localhost` or `--host=127.0.0.1`.

But I'm still wondering why does the IPv6 host work, but no other configuration? Has anyone run in the same problem before? Why is this problem windows specific and is there anything I can change about my setup?